# デザインパターンのIteratorについて

Tags: java, アルゴリズム, デザインパターン

プログラミング初心者でJavaでIteratorについて学んだのですが、

・Iteratorには大まかに二つ役割があって、それはIteratorクラスとAggregateクラスの二つなのですが、実際にJavaで提供されているAPIはIteratorがjava.util.Iteratorクラス(Enumerationというのもありました)、AggregateがArrayListやMap、Setなどのことだと考えていいのですか？

・デザインパターンの本を読んでいるとMainクラスを作る人とそれ以外のクラス(デザインパターンで作るクラス群)を作る人は別の人だと考えていいのですか？(つまり前者は仕様を読んでAPIを利用する側)

いまいち理解が曖昧で確証が持てなくてもやもやしています。
どなたか御回答お願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GoFデザインパターンによる「[Iteratorパターン](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_%E3%83%91%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3)」と、Java標準ライブラリが提供する「[`Iterator`インタフェース](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)」とを区別して説明します。

- Iteratorパターン：「データ集合の要素走査」を目的としたクラス設計構造に名前をつけたもの。
- Iteratorインタフェース：Java言語でIteratorパターンを実現する際に利用するAPI。

---

> Iteratorには大まかに二つ役割があって、それはIteratorクラスとAggregateクラスの二つなのですが、実際にJavaで提供されているAPIはIteratorがjava.util.Iteratorクラス(Enumerationというのもありました)、AggregateがArrayListやMap、Setなどのことだと考えていいのですか？

概ね正しい解釈と思います。より正確に表現するならば：

- Iteratorパターンはインタフェースを規定する「(抽象)Iteratorクラス」「(抽象)Aggregateクラス」、それらを実装する「ConcreteIteratorクラス」「ConcreteAggregateクラス」で記述される。
- Java言語の[`java.util.Iterator`インタフェース](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)は、Iteratorパターンの「(抽象)Iteratorクラス」に対応する。
- Java言語の[`java.util.Collection`インタフェース](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)は、Iteratorパターンの「(抽象)Aggregateクラス」に対応する。
- Java言語の`ArrayList`, `Map`, `Set`等は、Iteratorパターンの「ConcreteAggregateクラス」に対応する。

---

> デザインパターンの本を読んでいるとMainクラスを作る人とそれ以外のクラス(デザインパターンで作るクラス群)を作る人は別の人だと考えていいのですか？(つまり前者は仕様を読んでAPIを利用する側)

どちらのケースもありえます。デザインパターンはソフトウェアの「設計(Design)を類型化したもの」に過ぎません。あるデザインパターンに従ったクラス設計を、第三者が行ってあなたがそれを利用するケースもあれば、あなた自身が記述するクラス設計がデザインパターンに従うこともあります。